# Observable data not persisted

Tags: javascript, rxjs

When I `console.log(this.distances)`, it's available but not stored in memory. How can I store it in memory so as to use it? Even if I run a function after the data arives, I still get error of the array been `null`.

Here is my function:

```
findClosestRiderToUser() { 
    this.fetchAllRiders().subscribe( async distance => {        
      await this.distances.push( distance );
    });
}
```

Issue: trying to use `this.distances` outside of the subscription is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: if one part of the function is async, the whole thing must be async. Format your code a little bit, show us where you've tried to do console.log

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: async / await is one method of handling asynchronous data, observables are another, don't mix them.

Answer (score 1):

Observables are typically asynchronous, so

```
obs$.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
console.log(this.data);
```

will not work in many or most cases because the second line is run before the data arrived. What you want to do instead is

```
obs$.subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    console.log(this.data);
});
```

If you want to have this call in a function, just return the observable from the function and subscribe from the caller:

```
function getData() { return obs$; }
getData().subscribe(...);
```

rxjs comes with many operators that allow you to further combine, chain and manipulate observables. This way you stay fully async and don't have to use `await` to block execution of the code.

If you absolutely *do* want to block, you can use

```
const data = await obs$.toPromise();
```

But you should try and work with the reactive pattern instead of putting the brakes on it the first chance you get. You also lose observable's power to emit a stream of data rather than just single values.

Comment: ok. great! another issue am having is instead of getting one single array containing 3 objects . am getting 3 arrays instead. source code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXPOWe

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted with the green checkmark. For a new question please open a new thread where you can post the relevant code directly.